# Flextable : using superscript in the dataframe

Tags: html, markdown, r-markdown, flextable

This question was asked few times, but surprinsingly, no answer was given.

I want some numbers in my dataframe to appear in superscript.
The functions `compose` and `display` are not suitable here since I don't know yet which values in my dataframe will appear in superscript (my tables are generated automatically).

I tried to use `^8^`like for `kable`, `$$10^-3$$`, `paste(expression(10^2))`,  `"H\\textsubscript{123}"`, etc.

Nothing works !! Help ! I pull out my hair...

```
library(flextable)
bab = data.frame(c( "10\\textsubscript{-3}", 
paste(as.expression(10^-3)), '10%-3%', '10^-2^' ))
flextable(bab)
```

I am knitting from `R`to html.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that.  Have you tried using `knitr::kable` and `kableExtra` instead?  Why choose `flextable`?

Comment: @user2554330 It's a long story ! I used `flextable` because I needed to merge some  cells in my table. It was much easier with `flextable. It took me a day od adaptation to change my code from `kableExtra` to `flextable`.

Comment: See my questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58132626/rmarkdown-can-we-merge-two-cells-with-kableextra and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113321/is-there-a-way-of-making-beautiful-tables-for-word-in-r. Thanks a lot for your suggestion !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HTML, you do superscripts using things like `<sup>-3</sup>`, and subscripts using `<sub>-3</sub>`.  However, if you put these into a cell in your table, you'll see the full text displayed, it won't be interpreted as HTML, because `flextable` escapes the angle brackets.

The `kable()` function has an argument `escape = FALSE` that can turn this off, but `flextable` doesn't:  see https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/156.  However, there's a hackish way to get around this limitation:  replace the `htmlEscape()` function with a function that does nothing.

For example,

````
```{r}
library(flextable)
env <- parent.env(loadNamespace("flextable")) # The imports
unlockBinding("htmlEscape", env)
assign("htmlEscape", function(text, attribute = FALSE) text, envir=env)
lockBinding("htmlEscape", env)
bab = data.frame(x = "10<sup>-3</sup>")
flextable(bab)
```
````

This will display the table as

[image: screenshot]

Be careful if you do this:  there may be cases in your real tables where you really do want HTML escapes, and this code will disable that for the rest of the document.  If you execute this code in an R session, it will disable escaping for the rest of the session.

And if you were thinking of using a document like this in a package you submit to CRAN, forget it.  You shouldn't be messing with bindings like this in code that you expect other people to use.

**Edited to add:**

In fact, there's a way to do this without the hack given above.  It's described in this article:  https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/display.html#sugar-functions-for-complex-formatting.  The idea is to replace the entries that need superscripts or subscripts with calls to `as_paragraph`, `as_sup`, `as_sub`, etc.:

````
```{r}
library(flextable)
bab <- data.frame(x = "dummy")
bab <- flextable(bab)
bab <- compose(bab, part = "body", i = 1, j = 1,
         value = as_paragraph("10",
                              as_sup("-3")))
bab
```
````

This is definitely safer than the method I gave.

Comment: I've added another solution.

Comment: I watched these functions; but in my case, I find them difficult to use because the expressions to replace are not in a specific cell but placed randomly in the table. Moreover, in these cells, there is other information than the expression with the superscript. I think I could create a function with `gsub` but it would be hard work.

Comment: Thanks for the second solution anyway :-)

Comment: @FloraGrappelli may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896192/use-flextabledisplay-in-a-function